# richfaces rich:contextMenu disappears in IE6 when onmouseout on calling div is executed

Tags: richfaces, internet-explorer-6, contextmenu, onmouseout

I've created a div with a componentControl that should open a contextmenu

```
<div id="I32" onmouseover="some jquery function" onmouseout ="other jquery function">
    <rich:componentControl attachTo="IE32" event="oncontextmenu" for="infmenu" operation="show">
    </rich:componentControl>
</div>
```

The contextmenu is generaly like this

```
<rich:contextMenu  attached="false" id="infmenu" submitMode="ajax" >
some <rich:menuItem> and <rich:menuGroup> tags
</rich:contextMenu>
```

In IE6, when I try to hover over this contextMenu, the onmouseout function of my div is called and the contextMenu disappears. When i delete the onmouseout parameter from my div, the contextmenu remains visible.

The onmouseout function is like this:
    jQuery('#I32').removeClass('classA'); jQuery('#I31').addClass('classB');

Does anyone have any idea why this does not work?

Firefox, IE9 and IE9 in compatibility mode do work like expected.

Comment: I got same problem, any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Only found this issue in JBoss community (fixed for IE 7): https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-3187

Comment: The only thing that works for me is deactivating the mouseout event. IE7 does not have this issue. I don't know enough javascript to debug this issue.

Comment: which RichFaces version are you using? for eg.: version 3.3.3 supports IE 7+, it will be buggy when run on IE 6.

Comment: I do use version 3.3.3. In the dev guide they say IE6+ ? http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/TechnicalRequirements.html

Comment: Although they say IE6+, but I strongly believe that it won't, 'cause IE6 was delivered out of the web standard world.
Even though running on IE7, it still persist some problem. Only IE8+ fully follows the web standard, and it's recommended.